# iOS: getting all classes in a bundle, or loaded app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to get a list of classes loaded in an app at runtime.  I don't care about ALL classes, just those loaded.  I know how to get a list of all classes, but iterating through them checking to see if they are in the loaded bundle results in random crashes and seems like an overkill way to do it.

I have seen references to NSLoadedClasses, but I can't find anything about that really, and I'm not sure it's applicable to iOS (vs Mac).  What is the correct way to go about getting this? Again, I need it at runtime.

Comment: I'm wondering *why* you'd want to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like I figured it out.  If you need to do this, here's how to do it:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <dlfcn.h>
#import <mach-o/ldsyms.h>


unsigned int count;
const char **classes;
Dl_info info;

dladdr(&_mh_execute_header, &info);
classes = objc_copyClassNamesForImage(info.dli_fname, &count);

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  NSLog(@"Class name: %s", classes[i]);
  Class class = NSClassFromString ([NSString stringWithCString:classes[i] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
  // Do something with class

}
```